# When save data into database. All of my fields are changed but my list isn't. Why?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, thymeleaf

When I update the recipe, my ingredients field (HashSet) is not changing after I update. When I get into the `updateRecipe()` method. My `Recipe` that I receive, all the fields have data (ingredients have 8 elements). But when I submit the form update, the ingredients field, I get from the FORM change from 8 to 0 elements, then I save it to database, all of the field that I change is changed but the ingredient field (`HashSet`) still 8 not 0. Why is this happening?

Class `Recipe`:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Recipe {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String description;
    private Integer prepTime;
    private Integer cookTime;
    private Integer servings;
    private String source;
    private String url;

    @Lob
    private String directions;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "recipe")
    private Set<Ingredient> ingredients = new HashSet<>();

    @Lob
    private Byte[] image;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private Difficulty difficulty;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Notes notes;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "recipe_category",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
    private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();

    public void setNotes(Notes notes) {
        if (notes != null) {
            this.notes = notes;
            notes.setRecipe(this);
        }
    }

    public Recipe addIngredient(Ingredient ingredient){
        ingredient.setRecipe(this);
        this.ingredients.add(ingredient);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Class `RecipeCommand`:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RecipeCommand {
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 3, max = 255)
    private String description;

    @Min(1)
    @Max(999)
    private Integer prepTime;

    @Min(1)
    @Max(999)
    private Integer cookTime;

    @Min(1)
    @Max(100)
    private Integer servings;
    private String source;

    @URL
    @NotBlank
    private String url;

    @NotBlank
    private String directions;

    private Set<IngredientCommand> ingredients = new HashSet<>();
    private Difficulty difficulty;
    private NotesCommand notes;
    private Byte[] image;
    private Set<CategoryCommand> categories = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Class `Ingredient`:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"recipe"})
@Entity
public class Ingredient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String description;
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private UnitOfMeasure uom;

    @ManyToOne
    private Recipe recipe;
}
```

Class `IngredientCommand`:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class IngredientCommand {
private Long id;
private Long recipeId;
private String description;
private BigDecimal amount;
private UnitOfMeasureCommand uom;
}
```

Recipe Service:

```
    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("recipe/{id}/update")
    public String updateRecipe(@PathVariable String id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("recipe", recipeService.findCommandById(Long.valueOf(id)));
        return  "recipe/recipeform";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("recipe")
    public String saveOrUpdate(@Valid @ModelAttribute("recipe") RecipeCommand command, BindingResult result){
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            log.error("Have some error");
            return "recipe/recipeform";
        }
    
        RecipeCommand savedCommand = recipeService.saveRecipeCommand(command);
    
        Recipe afterSave = recipeService.findById(savedCommand.getId());
        return "redirect:/recipe/" + savedCommand.getId() + "/show";
    }
```

My page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    Recipe Form

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"
          th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
    
    <script src="/webjars/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
            crossorigin="anonymous" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>



<!--/*@thymesVar id="recipe" type="guru.springframework.domain.Recipe"*/-->

    
        
            

                <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}" class="alert alert-danger">
                    <p>Please Correct Errors Below</p>
                </div>
    
                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
                <div class="panel-group">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h1 th:text="#{recipe.description}" class="panel-title">Edit Recipe Information</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('description')}
                                ? 'col-md-3 form-group has-error' : 'col-md-3 form-group'">
                                    <label>Recipe Description:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{description}" th:errorclass="has-error"/>
                                    <span class="help-block" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('description')}">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('description')}" th:text="${err}"/>
                                        </ul>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                    <label>Categories:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-9 form-group">
                                    <div class="radio">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" value=""/>
                                            Cat 1
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="radio" th:remove="all">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" value=""/>
                                            Cat 2
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('prepTime')}
                                ? 'col-md-3 form-group has-error' : 'col-md-3 form-group'">
                                    <label>Prep Time:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{prepTime}" th:errorclass="has-error"/>
                                    <span class="help-block" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('prepTime')}">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('prepTime')}" th:text="${err}"/>
                                        </ul>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('cookTime')}
                                ? 'col-md-3 form-group has-error' : 'col-md-3 form-group'">
                                    <label>Cooktime:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{cookTime}" th:errorclass="has-error"/>
                                    <span class="help-block" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('cookTime')}">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('cookTime')}" th:text="${err}"/>
                                        </ul>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                    <label>Difficulty:</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" th:field="*{difficulty}">
                                        <option th:each="difficultyValue : ${T(guru.springframework.domain.Difficulty).values()}"
                                                th:value="${difficultyValue.name()}"
                                                th:text="${difficultyValue.name()}"
                                        >val
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                    <select class="form-control" th:remove="all">
                                        <option>Easy</option>
                                        <option>Medium</option>
                                        <option>Hard</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('servings')}
                                ? 'col-md-3 form-group has-error' : 'col-md-3 form-group'">
                                    <label>Servings:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{servings}" th:errorclass="has-error"/>
                                    <span class="help-block" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('servings')}">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('servings')}" th:text="${err}"/>
                                        </ul>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                                    <label>Source:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{source}"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group" th:class="${#fields.hasErrors('url')}
                                ? 'col-md-3 form-group has-error' : 'col-md-3 form-group'">
                                    <label>URL:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{url}" th:errorclass="has-error"/>
                                    <span class="help-block" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('url')}">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('url')}" th:text="${err}"/>
                                        </ul>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-11 ">
                                    <h1 class="panel-title">Ingredients</h1>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1">
                                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#"
                                       th:href="@{'/recipe/' + ${recipe.id} + '/ingredients'}" role="button">View</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <ul th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(recipe.ingredients)}">
                                        <li th:remove="all">1 Cup of milk</li>
                                        <li th:remove="all">1 Teaspoon of chocolate</li>
                                        <li th:remove="all">asdf</li>
                                        <li th:each="ingredient : ${recipe.ingredients}"
                                            th:text="${(ingredient.getAmount() +
                                        ' ' + ingredient.uom.getDescription() +
                                        ' - ' + ingredient.getDescription())}">1 Teaspoon of Sugar
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h1 class="panel-title">Directions</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" th:field="*{directions}"></textarea></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h1 class="panel-title">Notes</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" th:field="*{notes.recipeNotes}"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you have pour only part of your RecipeController where your RecipeService should be...